# display data from database that i login

Tags: php

I'm newbie in php. I login as admin and password blah blah blah. I redirect page login.php to the page adminMain.php. in adminMain.php

I want to display welcome **__ as __**. that empty space is data I call from database. welcome azlan as admin.

azlan is user id and admin is userrole in database, but when I try this coding, it do appear. but it appear with another user too.

example : welcome azlan as admin and welcome abu as admin

how do I need to do to set that data display based on which admin I logged in.

thanks. this is my adminMain.php

```
<?php

 mysql_connect("localhost","mhmdazlan","baby900") or die(mysql_error());
 mysql_select_db("epbthelpdesk") or die(mysql_error());

 $query = "SELECT * FROM login"; 
 $result = mysql_query($query); 
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
  {
     echo $row['username'] . " " . $row['userrole'];
        echo "<br>";
  }


?>
```

Comment: The MySQL family of PHP is deprecated and support thereof will disappear. Please look into [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [Mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php). I hope that's not your actual password in the code there.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM login` returns every row from the login table. You need to add a `WHERE` clause to the query to add the username of the user that logged in. You'll need that for the login procedure itself too, because you need to validate the user name and password against the existing accounts.

Answer (score 0):

it is difficult without seeing your code but at the moment you are pulling every single field from login. should be like

$query = "SELECT * FROM login where username ='$username' and userrole = '$userrole' ";

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
https://github.com/joshcam/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class
```

Sample code

```
<?php

require_once ('MysqliDb.php');

$db = new MysqliDb ('localhost', 'mhmdazlan', 'baby900', 'epbthelpdesk');

if(isset($_POST['username'])) $username = $_POST['username']; else die('no username');

$cols = array("username", "userrole");
$db->where("username", $username);
$user = $db->getOne("login",$cols);

if($user) {
    var_dump($user);
}
else die('no user');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    <?php


      $con=mysql_connect("localhost","mhmdazlan","baby900","epbthelpdesk");
     // Check connection
     if (mysql_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_connect_error();
     }
      $query = "SELECT * FROM login"; 
      $result = mysql_query($query,$con); 
      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
      {
          echo $row['username'] . " " . $row['userrole'];
          echo "<br>";
      }


    ?>
```

Comment: yes it appear . but it appear all admin and user in database data. i want it appear data from user that i logged in .

Comment: Change you query like 'SELECT * FROM login WHERE username=your entered username LIMIT 1' or you can pass the user id also.

Answer (score 0):

you want to fetch only the information of the logged in admin.
So you must use [where](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-where-clause.htm) clause in your query.

```
  <?php

 mysql_connect("localhost","mhmdazlan","baby900") or die(mysql_error());
 mysql_select_db("epbthelpdesk") or die(mysql_error());

 $query = "SELECT * FROM login where username=your entered name"; 
 $result = mysql_query($query); 
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
  {
     echo $row['username'] . " " . $row['userrole'];
        echo "<br>";
  }


?>
```